# Cheap mic for 5D to help Plural Eyes with sync 

Tags: plural-eyes, sync

Next week I'm going to be on a shoot in Mexico, which will be shot on three 5Ds, and they're going to use Plural Eyes to sync.

What is the absolute cheapest mic that I can plug in straight into the 5D as a guide track? I'm not interested in quality, it's purely to help with sync.

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful in Mexico. Place is crazy these days. :)

Comment: @C3Sound you referring to the 20 tourists found in the burial ground? I have my shotgun (mic) with me so I'm safe ;-) 

Answer (score 1):

Just for syncing, really the internal mic is not bad.  I actually used some of the sound from one to blend into foley.

That said, if you want some safety, the [Audio-Technica Pro-24CM](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/518701-REG/Audio_Technica_PRO_24_CM_Pro_24CM_Stereo_Microphone.html) runs about $70 online and is stereo.  Gets decent reviews.  Stepping it up, you can go for the [Rode VideoMic](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/363083-REG/Rode_VIDEOMIC_VideoMic_Camera_Mounted.html) at $150.  The A-T runs off of LR-44 batteries (cost about $1 each) and the Rode runs off of 9V.

Comment: I actually found a small in cam Sony mic, which should work perfectly. It's the first mic I ever bought :-) Thanks for the answer though!  

Comment: Cool! Btw... PluralEyes - so flippin cool!

Answer (score 1):

If you're shooting with anything at about 80mm or closer the internal mic will work great.  I just finished shooting a doc almost entirely with a 50mm lens and a 38mm lens (under a highway) and have been able to sync everything pretty well, though I'm doing it manually since I don't own plural eyes yet.

between 50 to 120mm glass or so a camera mount shotgun can help, but noise may still affect the quality of what plural eyes can do.

Once you get out really long no shotgun will help you, and you'll have to take a wireless feed in.